# How can I instruct Python copy paste *values* from one cell in excel to another?

Tags: python, excel

I am new to python and my request is very basic.

Please can you tell me how to make Python copy  and paste *values* from one cell in one excel worksheet to another cell in a worksheet?

I have tried this method, but i get attribution error. The cell, to be copied from, has a formula in it hence I need it to paste just the value in that cell.

I have tried this:

`sheet0 = workbook.sheets['Output sheet'] sheet2 = workbook.sheets['Main'] sheet0.clear_contents() sheet2.range('AK2').value = sheet0.range('A1')` <--- this line doesn't work.

So I am trying to copy what's in cell AK2, in the "main" worksheet and paste (the values) in the "Output Sheet" cell A1.

The library I am using is xlwings.

Comment: you  probably need to say what library you're using to read and write the excel format.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post.

The library I am using is xlwings. Does that help?

Comment: If you **clear** the contents of `sheet0` **first**, how do you expect to get the value of `sheet0.range('A1')`?

Comment: I thought that my script above was clearing Sheet0. But then copying from sheet2 and pasting the values into sheet0?

Going by your response, It sounds like its copying from sheet0 and pasting in sheet2?
I am very new to this, would you be able to fix the script so that it does what I would like it to do?

Thanks,